# Get MAC address of all visible Access Points using Managed Wifi API

Tags: .net, wifi, managed

Is there a way to get the BSSID (MAC address) of all available access points arround by using Managed Wifi API in C# / VB.net ?

What i have so far only gives me SSID, Encryption and Strength (gain) percentage.

```
        For Each wlanIface As NativeWifi.WlanClient.WlanInterface In client.Interfaces
        Dim networks As Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork() = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0)
        For Each network As Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork In networks
            Dim ssid As Wlan.Dot11Ssid = network.dot11Ssid
            Dim networkName As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ssid.SSID, 0, CInt(ssid.SSIDLength))


            Dim item As New ListViewItem(networkName)
            item.SubItems.Add(network.dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm.ToString())
            item.SubItems.Add(network.wlanSignalQuality & "%")
            ListView1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    Next
```

I found a solution by using the Native Wlan API but it's a little bit buggy because it requests the mac address based on the SSID, which means, if i have more than one Access Points with the same SSID, i will end up with the same BSSID for each of them.

Any other ways of getting the current (in the loop) AP's BSSID other than that?

I need a "managed" way, not a hacky netsh-parsing one. I did it with netsh but the computer's language is a problem.